# What do I need to do to be able to use filter objects that have a property greater than or equal to date?

Tags: django

The query `organisation.datapoint_set.filter'timestamp='2014-12-12'` returns one entity.

The query `organisation.datapoint_set.filter'timestamp_gte='2014-12-12'` returns zero entities.

I also get the error message:

> *** FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'timestamp_gte' into field. Choices are ...

What changes do I need to make to be able to use a greater than or equal filter on timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use double underscore:

```
organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte='2014-12-12')
```